# Declare variable in php file that will access in JS/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I declare a global variable in a `PHP` file and access directly in `jQuery`?

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
   var date_selected = <?php echo $from; ?>;
</script>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
   alert("dsdsadasdas" + date_selected);
   var date = date_selected;
   var startDate;
   var endDate;
});
```

Because on my test its not working.

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: have you included the file that holds your global variable into your accessed file?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the quotes

```
var date_selected = '<?php echo $a; ?>';
```

Comment: or `echo json_encode($a);` this would properly escape any `'` in $a